# Simulate button click JS, for clipboard manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to simulate a button click, so i can call

```
<button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

which uses the https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard library to manipulate the clipboard.

I am trying to write to the client clipboard on hover of button.

```
<button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>

   <script>  
   var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
       moviePath: "/js/ZeroClipboard.swf"
   } );
   clip.on( 'mouseover', function(client) {
       clip.setText( "Got in" );
       $('#copy-button').simulateClick();
       alert("fired");
   } );

       $.fn.simulateClick = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
            if('createEvent' in document) {
                var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
            } else {
                this.click(); // IE
            }
            });
        }
  </script>
```

I do get the event handler "mouseover" to fire, but i cannot seem to simulate the button click

Comment: From a cursory glance, ZeroClipboards by overlaying a Flash "movie" **over** the button, so an actual mouse click will be intercepted by said movie. Simulating a click on the button under the movie won't do anything. Seems like you'd have to call `clip.setText()` instead.

Comment: Yes but that wont fire the event :(

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to simulate the click instead of just calling the event handler for the click directly? Also, have you tried using the jQuery method `$(this).click()`?